# HTML code from w3school to creat a modal with tabbed content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I went to w3school link below that shows you how to create a modal with tabbed contents

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_tab

I changed the code to add another button to open its own tabbed content but it does not display its content unless I press on it. The code after I modify it looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<style>
.city {display:none}
</style>
<body class="w3-container"><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn">Open Tabbed Modal</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-btn">Open Tabbed Modal 02</button>
<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
 <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom">
  <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
   <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
   class="w3-closebtn w3-padding-top">&times;</span>
   <h2>Header</h2>
  </header>
  <ul class="w3-pagination w3-white w3-border-bottom" style="width:100%;">
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>London</h1>
   <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>Paris</h1>
   <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>Tokyo</h1>
   <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p><br>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding">
   <button class="w3-btn w3-right w3-white w3-border"
   onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
 <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom">
  <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
   <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'"
   class="w3-closebtn w3-padding-top">&times;</span>
   <h2>Header</h2>
  </header>
  <ul class="w3-pagination w3-white w3-border-bottom" style="width:100%;">
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'London2')">London</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris2')">Paris</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo2')">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="London2" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>London 2</h1>
   <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Paris2" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>Paris 2</h1>
   <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Tokyo2" class="w3-container city">
   <h1>Tokyo 2</h1>
   <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p><br>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding">
   <button class="w3-btn w3-right w3-white w3-border"
   onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[0].click();
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("w3-light-grey");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("w3-light-grey");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the trick is in the first line after **script** tag where it says:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[0].click();
```

but I don't know how to figure it out

Comment: The code you posted is exactly the same as on W3Schools. Can you [edit] to show your code?

Comment: sorry I pasted the same code, please review now

Comment: @4castle   Hi, can you please advice on this issue

Comment: Add this line of code `document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[3].click();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want open it after loading add:

```
document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
```

This chose which tab will be open:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")[1].click();
```